# How to stop variable re initializing in context

Tags: reactjs, use-context

I have a variable in my context with the base url for my api and i add parameters to that base call to add parameters, the problem that i have is that i can't concatenate more than one parameter at a time, so if for example set my checkbox for one brand the url updates to that brand filter and the function adds the brand filter parameter, but if i search something the url re-initialites itself and deletes the other parameter.

Some images for more clarity:
If i make a search:
[image]

The url console logs like this, the line 87 logs the url before i concatenate the parameter and the 91 after i concatenate the parameter:

[image]

And if i check the Nike brand that should only show the Nike Air Yeezy product and url should be "http://localhost:5000/api/v1/products?name=Yeezy&company=Nike" is only "http://localhost:5000/api/v1/products?company=Nike&"

[image]

[image]

My theory is that as i declarate the base url parameter every time i do one function the context resets and that url var re initializes, but how can i stop this? I searched at how to make a string state and concatenating that state but couldn't find anything.

Here is the part of the context where i handle the new api calls, if something seems weird/missing is because i cut the context to make it more clear

```
  var url = "/api/v1/products?";
  const [productList, setProductList] = useState([]);
  const [brandFilter, setBrandFilter] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState({
    text: "",
  });

  const getProductList = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const responseJson = await response.json();
    if (responseJson) {
      setProductList(responseJson.products);
    }
  };



  useEffect(() => {
    getProductList();
  }, []);



  useEffect(() => {
    setSearchUrl();
    getProductList();
  }, [search]);

  const setBrandUrl = () => {
    console.log(url);
    if (brandFilter.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < brandFilter.length; i++) {
        url += `company=${brandFilter[i]}&`;
      }
    }
    console.log(url);
  };

  const setSearchUrl = () => {
    console.log(url);
    if (search.text != "") {
      url += `name=${search.text}`;
    }
    console.log(url);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setBrandUrl();
    getProductList();
  }, [brandFilter]);
```

Comment: maybe instead manipulate directly `url` string, keep selected values in a state and ``fetch(`${url}${brandState ? `company=${brandState}` : ''}${productNameState ? `name=${productNameState} : ''}`)``

Comment: Yes i kinda solved it doing something like that, but still im curious to see if there is a way to make the url variable not overwritting. Basically i made a function to concatenate both the Brands and search term and if i see in setBrandUrl and setSearchUrl that the brand filter state and the search state has something i call that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you've got the `useEffect` split into two; one which is reacting to the `search` changing, and one which is reacting to the `brands` changing. You need to combine those into one.

If we look at the effect for when the `search` changes, and we reduce the code to what's actually running, your effect is doing this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  var url = "/api/v1/products?";

  if (search.text != "") {
    url += `name=${search.text}`;
  }

  getProductList();
}, [search]);
```

i.e. it ignores `brandsFilter` completely. You need to have both the `brandsFilter` and the `search` as a dependency for a single effect:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  let url = "/api/v1/products?";

  if (search.text) {
    url += `name=${search.text}`;
  }

  if (brandsFilter.length) {
    const brands = brandsFilter.map(b => `&brand=${b}`).join('');
    url += search.text ? brands : brands.substr(1);
  }

  // NOTE: pass the 'url' to the get as a parameter here!
  getProductList(url);
}, [search, brandsFilter]);
```

Note: this is easier if you use a library like [`query-string`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) to do the heavy lifting for you:

```js
import qs from 'query-string';

useEffect(() => {
  const url = qs.stringifyUrl({
    url: "/api/v1/products?",
    query: {
        name: search.text || undefined,
        brands: brandsFilter,
    }
  });

  getProductList(url);
}, [search, brandsFilter]);
```

Comment: You just saved me from so much lines of code, it really makes sense that i shouldn't be splitting the useEffect. And also the query-string package is magic. TYSM for your time and answer :D

Comment: No worries, happy to help :-)